# diff of two folders excuding file types with OS X command line

Tags: macos, command-line, terminal, osx-mavericks

I found `diff -rq folder1 folder2` however, being an OS X user you get the lovely hidden files like `.DS_Store` just clouding up the results in the terminal. So, I really don't care about those files. Knowing the command line is powerful, and often contains many hidden gems. How can I do a diff on two folders. Excluding either one or more file(s)/types.

Note this isn't for something like rsync or git or svn. Since most of my searches for the answer I seek refer primarily to svn/git repositories..

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can exclude all files matching a certain pattern using the -x flag of diff. The following line should exclude all hidden files in all directories you diff:

```
diff -x '.*' -rq folder1 folder2
```

Comment: tyyyyyyyyyy. :)

Comment: Is there a way to exclude *only* `.DS_store` files? I don't want to exclude all hidden files.

Comment: Since it's a pattern match, I believe you can just do `diff -x '.DS_store' -rq folder1 folder2`